# How to get similar behavior between Garbage Collection in a longer-lived Single-Page Application and Multiple-Page Application?

Tags: javascript, memory-management, memory-leaks, garbage-collection, single-page-application

I've looked through the web and stack overflow, and nearly come to the point of believing that SPAs doesn't take much advantage of the currently GC algorithm.

Our team taked care about to destroy useless objects at state transitions, unbind stuffs,remove listeners, and all possibilities that we found on internet. But it still have a kind of memory leak on a long-lived SPA (1~2 constantly usage). It is possible to see a graph below that represents a memory usage in 2 hours of SPA navigation:

[image: 2 hours of SPA navigation graph]

It was a jump from 40 mb to 700 mb in 2 hours. Obviously, there are many features like maps and graphics that justify memory consumption, however, for an unused memory.

There is more things besides of this one listed above to improve GC on SPA?

We know that GC can not be controlled by the client(javascript), although there are some events that trigger this condition. Some user actions like: navigation, page exchange, closing tabs, among others, do not happen in a SPA.
How can I get a satisfactory result with memory management in a SPA ?

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried profiling in Chrome Developer Tools - in particular looking at [Allocation Timeline](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/memory-problems/#identify_js_heap_memory_leaks_with_allocation_timelines) to find out when memory is being requested?

Which SPA framework are you using: Angular (1, 2, 4), vue, ember, react, home grown...?

Comment: Yes I did.
Thanks for your awnser but the question is not about how to figure out leaks but how to get a similar GC workflow into a SPA like in a Multi page application, if possible.

I this case, AngularJS 1 and 2 are used.

But the same happens with other frameworks. 

I think it's a generalized issue for SPA.